# Scriptstyle has no effect - Chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Just noticed that adding \scriptstyle{\oplus} or \scriptsize{\oplus} doesn't actually change anything. I'm not sure if I have been using the command wrong (I'm trying to decrease the size of the \oplus), since I've included it in a lot of my other mechanisms. Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this.

Edit: Clarified the effect I expected to see
Edit 2: Changed incorrect charge on N from - to +

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]N^{\scriptstyle{\oplus}}H_3}
\chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]N^{\scriptsize{\oplus}}H_3}

\chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]N^{\oplus}H_3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: neither `\scriptstyle` nor `\scriptsize` take an argument so the following `{..}` are wrong. Superscripts are already in `\scriptstyle` so that would not be expected to do anything in a superscript, size commands like `\scriptsize` are not allowed in math mode. You have not said what effect you expected to see?

Comment: `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode on input line 21.`

Comment: My bad, I thought it would decrease the size of the \ominus as I previously used it to decrease the size of a delta+ symbol

Comment: as I say \scritptsize is an error and `\scriptstyle` selects the math style used in superscripts, If it reduced the size of a delta it was presumably not in a superscript. but `\scriptstyle{\delta} abc`  makes all of \delta a b and c superscript sized.

Comment: could I ask how I could scale the \ominus then? or could I just use scalebox{}

Comment: The charge location is *wrong altogether* (https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277, p. 374): "*In an atom label consisting of one non-hydrogen element symbol followed by the symbols for one or more hydrogen atoms, a charge symbol entered as text within the label should preferably be placed **after all of the hydrogen symbols**. **It should not be placed immediately before or after the non-hydrogen element symbol**. It is equally preferable to position the charge separately, **above or below** the non-hydrogen element symbol.*" ([**Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j0QD.png)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`\scriptsize` is invalid in math mode (and the syntax is `\scriptsize abc` not `\scriptsize{a}bc`) You get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode on input line 21.
```

`\scriptstyle` also does not take an argument but selects the size used in superscripts, so does nothing here. You can select scriptscriptstyle which is the smallest of the three math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]N^{\scriptscriptstyle \ominus}H_3}


\chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]N^{\ominus}H_3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: @GenericAccount unrelated by `tabu` is broken in current latex and unmaintained.

Answer (score 1):

No problem for me (TexLive 2021 and chemfig 1.6a). I suggest using the \chemabove command for a better result.

```
\chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle{\oplus}}H_3}
    
    \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]\chemabove{N}{\scriptsize{\oplus}}H_3}
    
    \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]\chemabove{N}{\oplus}H_3}
```

[image]

Comment: You're still making several of the mistakes that OP is making: `\scriptsize` is invalid in math mode, the `{}` are useless in `\scriptstyle{\oplus}`, and the only reason that `\scriptstyle` is working for you but not OP is because you've moved things from an exponent to `\chemabove`.

Comment: `\chemabove` isn't just a better result, it's the *correct* one according to IUPAC recommendations (https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277).

Comment: @Teepeemm - I kept the same commands used by "generic account" to show that this did not result in an error on my system.

Comment: @andselisk what about for mechanisms?

Comment: @GenericAccount What about them? Graphical representation standards don't change for each use case.

Comment: @andselisk ah okay, I misread what you wrote above. Thanks for the explanation